# How to retrieve a data from database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database

I have a question about how to get data from a database.

This is my code so far:

```
 public class TabController : Controller
 {
     private TestEntities db = new TestEntities();

     public ActionResult Index()
     {
         var model = GetTab();
         return View(model);
     }

     private IEnumerable<MN_REITER> GetReiter()
     {
        var reiters = Enumerable.Range(0,5).Select(
                i => new MN_REITER
                {                      
                    TabId = i,
                    TabDescription = "Tab "+i 
                   //REITER_LABEL = "Label" + i
                });

          return reiters;
      }
```

Like answer a have a Tab0 to Tab5, but I want a get the information from database.

Edit:

View.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable >rcMDM.Data.MN_REITER>
```

(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()

```
    .Name("reiterTab")

    .BindTo(Model, (item, reiter)=>
    {
        item.Text = reiter.REITER_BEZEICHNUNG;
       // item.Template.Html = reiter.REITER_LABEL;
    })
```

and the model

```
   public partial class MN_REITER
{
    public decimal REITERID { get; set; }
    public string REITER_BEZEICHNUNG { get; set; }
    public string REITER_LABEL { get; set; }
}
```

}

Comment: So you want get Tab details from database?

Comment: Yes, i want a get details from database. I have a column Tab_Label and i want to take the information from this column to the Tabs

Comment: So, you have already initialized DB (assuming `TestEntities` is your DB) in the controller. You can get the data using db?

Comment: Yes, the db conncetions are ok. I can get data from DB

Comment: Then you can use db.<EntityName> get method to retrieve the data.

Comment: Ok. You mean I can use db get method here:  { 
     var reiters = Enumerable.Range(0,5).Select(
               i => new MN_REITER

               {                      
                   TabId = i,
                   TabDescription = "Tab "+i 
                   //REITER_LABEL = "Label" + i
               });
   }
Or? Can you explain me a solution, i`m new in the work with EntityFramework und LINQ.

Comment: Then we need more details about your application like data access, entity, etc. Better you can start with this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started

Comment: I use a EntityFramework database First approach to connect the application with database.. Then i use a scaffoldcontrollers: 
Hier ist the Model: 
   public partial class MN_REITER
    {
        public decimal REITERID { get; set; }
        public string REITER_BEZEICHNUNG { get; set; }
        public string REITER_LABEL { get; set; }
    }
}

Comment: The View: 
@model IEnumerable<rcMDM.Data.MN_REITER>

@(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
        .Name("reiterTab")
        .BindTo(Model, (item, reiter)=>

        {
            item.Text = reiter.REITER_BEZEICHNUNG;
           // item.Template.Html = reiter.REITER_LABEL;
        })

Comment: the controller is explain on the top

Comment: Please update the model and view in the question.

Comment: I have updated the model and view